# Change type definition with a condition

Tags: typescript, types

Currently I have the following code:

```
declare const isBrowser: boolean;
declare const API: BrowserAPI & ElectronAPI;
```

allowing me to do something such as the following:

```
if (isBrowser) API.browserOnlyFunction();
```

which works great, but unfortunately because of the union, this makes it so I can use `API.browserOnlyFunction` anywhere.

What I want to do is the following:

```
API; // BrowserAPI | ElectronAPI

if (isBrowser) {
  API; // BrowserAPI
} else {
  API; // ElectronAPI
}
```

I've tried doing the following but with no avail:

```
declare const isBrowser: boolean;
declare const API: typeof isBrowser extends true ? BrowserAPI : ElectronAPI; // is always ElectronAPI
```

```
// having to pass API as an argument every time seems pretty ugly and repetitive to me
function browserAPI(API: BrowserAPI | ElectronAPI): API is BrowserAPI {
  if (isBrowser) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Is there any way I can do this with just the `isBrowser` constant or just a function that doesn't take any arguments?

Comment: You probably meant `declare const API: BrowserAPI | ElectronAPI;` in your first snippet, right?

Comment: Actually this is already possible if `isBrowser` has a concrete definition. TypeScript should be able to infer the type of `API` using `isBrowser` in control flow. Example: https://tsplay.dev/wReEYW

Comment: However if `API` itself has no feature to distinguish itself between `BrowserAPI` or `ElectronAPI` (correctly represented in types, too) then I don't think you can use this feature of TypeScript.

Comment: @mocha Having to add the (in your example) `isFlim` complicates things in my case. Is it not possible to have the `isBrowser` constant's value correspond to the type of `API` without changing either the `BrowserAPI` or `ElectronAPI` types? Of course there are differences between them but having to rely on this isn't great.